# Library written into more files

Tags: dart, package, dart-pub

I found a Dart library, which hasn't got any main lib.dart file with `library 'lib';` at the beginning, but which has more files with `library 'lib.sublib';` at the beginning. I understand this notation, but I have a question:

What if I want to have no main lib.dart file, but have eg three parts of my library as explained above and additionally I want to have one file, which joins all three sublibs into one for case if the user wants to use all three parts of the library?

What's right? See my two drafts below. Is any of them correct? Or should it be written anyhow else?

Draft I:

```dart
//lib.dart
library 'lib';
part 'superlib.dart';
part 'bestlib.dart';

//superlib.dart
part of 'lib';
...

//bestlib.dart
part of 'lib';
...
```

Draft II:

```dart
//lib.dart
library 'lib';
export 'superlib.dart';
export 'bestlib.dart';

//superlib.dart
library 'lib.super';
...

//bestlib.dart
library 'lib.best';
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both attempts are fine.

The first difference is that the parts can access private fields, functions, classes, class members (where the name starts with an underscore `_`) of each other part because they are in the same library.

The second difference is that the parts can not be imported individually by user if they are in the same library. Just the library itself could be imported.

Comment: And could any user really use one of parts from the 1st draft separatelly and individually? Like `import 'package:lib/bestlib.dart';` even if its beginning is `part of 'lib'`? (expecting yes, but better to ask)

Comment: Not this doesn't work. I thought the intention was to import the declarations of several files at once. Only with the 2nd attempt you can import each file individually.

Comment: That's the differrence I wanted to find out; Thank you